# Visual Studio 2017 - Intellisense was unable to determinate

Tags: jquery, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

i need to turn on jQuery Intellisense in VS2017, i've tried a lot of tips from web but only what i did was to enable Intellisense in html files:

[image]

But in any other js files that i want to join:

```
<script src="/script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After CTRL + SPACE shows the message:

[image]

Any one knows how can i turn on this in js files ?

Comment: Put a reference to `jquery` file in your `js` file

Comment: Add `/// <reference path="JS/jquery.js" />
/// <reference path="JS/jquery-vsdoc.js" />` to the top of your `js` file..

Comment: Thank you very much,its working! 
Actually i didn't know that is doubled, but yeah that Webmatrix topic is that what i was looking for

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)